# Insert commas into string flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have a string value as: June 22 2022 and I want to add comma with code such that it prints out this value: June 22, 2022. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Do you know the string value in advance?

Comment: I just want to add a separated comma just after the date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, you could use `DateTime`'s `DateFormatter`:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  DateFormat inputFormatter = DateFormat('MMMM dd yyyy');
  DateFormat outputFormatter = DateFormat('MMMM dd, yyyy');
  DateTime date = inputFormatter.parse('February 13 2042');
  String formatted = outputFormatter.format(date);
  print(formatted);
}
```

#### Console log

```
February 13, 2042
```

Comment: seems like it won't work if the month isn't spelt in full? e.g Feb 13 2042

Comment: That's why I said _in this particular case_. Where is the input date coming from? What are your specific requirements?

Comment: these are the way the dates are coming in from the backend. e.g Feb 20 2022, Mar 20 2021, Jan 12 2034. So, I needed to just add a comma separator after the date e.g Feb 20, 2022, Mar 20, 2021... 

Also, note that the months aren't spelt in full

Comment: If the months are always 3 letters, just change the formatters from `MMMM` to `MMM`. `MMMM` stands for full month names while `MMM` stands for abbreviated month names. You will find more info in the [`intl` package API](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html).